# PHP Upload IF ISSET always says it is?

Tags: php, image, upload

OK, i have some kind of strange problem with my code. I'm trying to make uploading form with text along photos. Now, I need to check if the photo is uploaded or the text is inserted only.

The simplified code looks like this:

```
if (isset ($_FILES['image'])){
echo 'yes';


} else {    
echo 'no';      
}
```

the form looks like:

```
   <form action=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-form">
   <form action=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-form">


   <label for="title"><strong>Title</strong> (required)</label>
   <input type="text" name="title" value="" required>


   <label><span class="small"><strong>Add a photo</strong></span></label>
   <input type="file" name="image"/>


   <input type="submit" name"submit" value="Submit">    
   </form>
```

Now, basically, what I'm trying to make is a check if file is attached or not, because I need an alternate option for posting posts without photos, in the same form; but, the problem is that no mather if it is attached or not it always says YES.

Help, anyone.

Comment: Try `if (!empty($_FILES['image'])) { ...`?

Comment: Nop, same thing happens. I insert the title only, it says the file has been inserted.

Comment: why it is 2 times `<form>` ??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To check if the file has been uploaded, how about:

```
if (!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    echo 'No upload';
}
else
{
    // Your file has been uploaded
}
```

[`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) is the choice here, check the docs out for it.

`$_FILES` is an array of files, and each file in the first dimension of the array is automatically given a `['tmp_name']` key in the second dimension, with the value being it's temporary location.

Obviously you then need to use `move_uploaded_file()` on the temporary file.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it with this.
P.s. uploading part isn't the problem (moving, entering db, everything works fine, this part was, when there is no file, just text) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking only that `$_FILES['image']` passed from your form.
But you are not checking that posted `$_FILES['image']` is empty or its contains a valid file data
Read more here http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

```
<?php
  if ( isset( $_FILES["image"] ) && !empty( $_FILES["image"]["name"] ) ) {
    if ( is_uploaded_file( $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] ) && $_FILES["image"]["error"] === 0 ) {
      // everything okay, do process
      echo 'yes';
      exit();
    }
  }
  echo 'no';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason "isset" doesn't work is most likely because $_FILES is considered set even when it is set to "null". I found the empty() suggestion to be the cleanest. Although, unless you're using a large form with multiple files, I would remove the brackets entirely.

```
if (empty ($_FILES)){
 echo 'No file';
 } else {    
 echo 'File found';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use empty() instead.

```
if (!empty ($_FILES['image'])){
    echo 'yes';


} else {    
    echo 'no';      
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, stil echoes 'yes' when the title is entered. I need 'no' :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){echo 'not attached successfully';}
else{echo 'attached successfully';}
```